# Will a combination AFCI mitigate all safety risks imposed by K&T?

Tags: wiring, afci, knob-and-tube

I know that properly working and regularly tested AFCI breakers are great for safety. But do they mitigate all safety risks imposed by knob-and-tube? If not, what safety risks remain?

For reference: our bedrooms and bathrooms have K&T. We don't use any high amperage devices in those rooms (absolutely no vacuums, gaming PCs, hair dryers, etc.) We're also not ready to chuck the money for a full rewiring quite yet.

Answer (score 1):

"othering" is fun. That's where you identify a group as "Bad", and pretend all others are "not bad".

It's a little too easy to say "Knob & Tube = bad".  They require AFCI on new construction, which isn't Knob & Tube, and isn't aluminum wires improperly placed on copper-only terminals and mistorqued.  It's mandated because *brand new* wiring - the stuff *you plan to replace the K&T **with*** - is on the same footing as K&T, really.  It fails too.

So yes -- AFCI breakers help, and will protect against arcing on any wiring. (The only place I don't see AFCI as useful is inside metal conduit, and it's always useful in bedrooms due to electric blankets.)

I would say GFCI helps more, because knob-n-tube usually means "no grounding".  GFCI removes the human-safety risks from lack of grounding.

Comment: I'd use "dufies" (dual function)  breakers.  Actually  do 4 things:  They have both types of arc fault protection, ground fault protection and over-current protection.   Not all K&T wiring is bad, some of it was real craftsmanship. But for the most part, it's best to be rid of it eventually.

Comment: So, with a properly rated, properly functioning "dual function" breaker, I should be good? My electrician is saying the "wires could still overheat" and wants to do a full rewire, but I don't necessarily buy that if the breaker is rated correctly for the wire gauge.